# How can I extract tweets through tweet IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to make a .txt file of certain tweets from the 2010 NFL. I want to write each tweet in a separate line. For the tweets that are unavailable/deleted, I want to have "--" in the corresponding line.

```py
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/karanpraharaj/Desktop/Saroj Kaushik Project/nfl-tweets-v1.0/tweets.nfl.2010.weekly.csv')
data.columns = ['tweet_id', 'tweet_UTCtime', 'team', 'opponent', 'week', 'home_away', 'score', 'opponent_score', 'point_spread', 'over_under']

tweetids = data['tweet_id']
tweetids = tweetids.values.reshape(-1,1) #Converting series object to np array

file1 = open("tweets2029.txt","w")

for i, tweetid in enumerate(tweetids):
    try:
        tweet = api.get_status(tweetid.item())
        file1.write('%d : ' %i)
        file1.write(tweet.text+ '\n')
    except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        file1.write('%d : -- \n')
        continue
```

When I tried the code below, I could only get 218 tweets written into my .txt file, all the other lines were "--". (I am new to coding so please excuse the bad code!)

Comment: You might want to replace your secret, token, key, etc with placeholders as it is a sensitive information. For example, replace with `consumer_secret = <CONSUMER_SECRET>`

Comment: How many tweet_id's are there in your csv? Have you tried to copy any of id's above 218 and check manually if it exists?

Comment: @wmatt - Yes, they all exist. What keeps happening is that the stream of tweets is on for a few minutes, and then it goes off and no tweets are collected for a few minutes and then it goes back on again. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Isn't that rate limit that you're exceeding? try init your api with wait_on_rate_limit, you will not get an exception when it is exceeded and tweepy will wait few minutes and start getting your tweets again, use something like this: api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)